# Merge two lists inside __init__ without instantiation. Python

Tags: python, class, variables

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_one = [1, 2, 3]


class Bar(object):
    def init(self):
        self.list_two = Foo.list_one + [4, 5, 6] # I know this won't work unless I 
                                                 # make list_one a class level variable
```

So, the question is - is there any way to merge those lists without instantiation of `Foo` or making `list_one` a class level variable?

Maybe there is a way of doing so using inheritance and `super()` but I can't understand how do I access variables inside methods with it. I also would be very grateful for an answer how to do it without using inheritance.

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve?

Comment: If you don't need instances to the point of avoidn them, you should not use classes at all - just use function calls, and pass the needed state in the parameters.

Comment: @JakobBowyer I want to `list_two`to be an extension of `list_one`, keeping them both inside `__init__` of their respective classes.

Comment: It would be best if you shared your broader goal because on the surface your requirement doesn't make sense, so our answers will not be that great either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to do the exact thing you describe. `self` is a reference to an instance of `Foo`, and doesn't exist until the class is instantiated; and `list_one` is an attribute of `self`, assigned to `self` after it has already been created. So `list_one` doesn't exist at all until after the class has been instantiated.

To do what you're asking using inheritance is fairly simple, however:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_one = [1, 2, 3]

class Bar(Foo):
    def init(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.list_two = self.list_one + [4, 5, 6]
        # if you want to discard list_one, you can, but that seems wrong somehow
        # del self.list_one
```

More generally, it's not really meaningful to refer to "variables inside methods" except during the execution of the method or function, or when referring to what's called the *closure* created by the function. Every time a function is called, a new namespace is created, and local variable names are created anew inside that namespace.

It is possible to refer to them once the function has been called, though. For example:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     a = x
...     def bar():
...         print a
...     return bar
... 
>>> bar1 = foo(5)
>>> bar2 = foo(6)
>>> bar1()
5
>>> bar2()
6
```

Observe that the two versions of `bar` refer to different values of `a`, each of which were created when `foo(5)` and `foo(6)` were called.

Answer (score 2):

Short of extreme bytecode hackery, no – it's impossible to pull a value out of a function and use it inside another function.

Additionally, since `Bar` is not a subclass of `Foo` and Python imposes a fairly arbitrary type check restriction on calling instance methods with an explicit `self`, you *can't* do something sensible like:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        Bar.__init__(self)
        self.list_one += [4, 5, 6]
```

Maybe you should make a class-level getter on `Foo` which returns the list?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_one = self.get_list_one()

    @classmethod
    def get_list_one(cls):
        return [1, 2, 3]
```